# prestashop 1.6 how to show manufacturer logo in productcontroller.php

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I want to show manufacturer logo image if product have no image.

I find on ProductController.php this:

```
if (!isset($cover)) {
            if (isset($images[0])) {
                $cover = $images[0];
                $cover['id_image'] = (Configuration::get('PS_LEGACY_IMAGES') ? ($this->product->id.'-'.$images[0]['id_image']) : $images[0]['id_image']);
                $cover['id_image_only'] = (int)$images[0]['id_image'];
            } else {
                $cover = array(
                    'id_image' => $this->context->language->iso_code.'-default',
                    'legend' => 'No picture',
                    'title' => 'No picture'
                );
            }
        }
```

but i don't know how to put manufacturer logo instead of no picture.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code to get product manufacturer image in ProductController.php

```
$man_id = $this->product->id_manufacturer;
$image_url = _PS_MANU_IMG_DIR_.$man_id'-medium.jpg';
```

Answer (score 0):

You must do a combination of changes in `ProductController.php` and `product.tpl`

```
        if (!isset($cover)) {
            if (isset($images[0])) {
                $cover = $images[0];
                $cover['id_image'] = (Configuration::get('PS_LEGACY_IMAGES') ? ($this->product->id.'-'.$images[0]['id_image']) : $images[0]['id_image']);
                $cover['id_image_only'] = (int)$images[0]['id_image'];
            } else {
                $cover = array(
                'id_image' => $this->context->language->iso_code.'-default',
                'legend' => 'No picture',
                'title' => 'No picture'
                );  //here your modification code
                $manufacturer_image = _PS_MANU_IMG_DIR_.$item['id_manufacturer'].'-'.ImageType::getFormatedName('medium').'.jpg'; 
             }
        }
```

Then in TPL:

```
              {if $have_image}
                    <span id="view_full_size">
                        {if $jqZoomEnabled && $have_image && !$content_only}
                            <a class="jqzoom" title="{if !empty($cover.legend)}{$cover.legend|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}{else}{$product->name|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}{/if}" rel="gal1" href="{$link->getImageLink($product->link_rewrite, $cover.id_image, 'thickbox_default')|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}">
                                <img itemprop="image" src="{$link->getImageLink($product->link_rewrite, $cover.id_image, 'large_default')|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}" title="{if !empty($cover.legend)}{$cover.legend|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}{else}{$product->name|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}{/if}" alt="{if !empty($cover.legend)}{$cover.legend|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}{else}{$product->name|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}{/if}"/>
                            </a>
                        {else} 
                            <img id="bigpic" itemprop="image" src="{$link->getImageLink($product->link_rewrite, $cover.id_image, 'large_default')|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}" title="{if !empty($cover.legend)}{$cover.legend|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}{else}{$product->name|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}{/if}" alt="{if !empty($cover.legend)}{$cover.legend|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}{else}{$product->name|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}{/if}" width="{$largeSize.width}" height="{$largeSize.height}"/>
                            {if !$content_only}
                                <span class="span_link no-print">{l s='View larger'}</span>
                            {/if}
                        {/if}
                    </span>
                {else} 
                    {* here you modification code *} <span id="view_full_size">
                        <img itemprop="image" src="{$manufacturer_image}" id="bigpic" alt="" title="{$product->name|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}" width="{$largeSize.width}" height="{$largeSize.height}"/>
                        {if !$content_only}
                            <span class="span_link">
                                {l s='View larger'}
                            </span>
                        {/if}
                    </span>
                {/if}
```

If you want the same behavior in all shop (cart, viewed productos, etc) you must override all specific controller that manage this views (`CartController`, etc).
Other more simple option that I personally don't like but could work is set a default image for every product without images, and this image should be the manufacturer image. To do this automatically you should subscribe to all Image entity hooks (`actionObjectImageAddAfter`, `actionObjectImageUpdateAfter`, `actionObjectImageDeleteAfter`) and check if product does not have images any more to placed a default manufacturer image in his place. Then when a real image is added delete the "default one".

```
    public function hookActionObjectImageUpdateAfter($params)
    {
        if (!Image::getImagesTotal((int) $params['object']->id_product))
        {
              //create an image for this product with manufacturer image
        }
    }
```

Good luck.

Comment: I try your suggestion in ProductController.php but don't work.

Comment: On Product.php I already have this `code`<img itemprop="image" src="{$img_manu_dir}{$product_manufacturer->id}-large_default.jpg" id="bigpic" alt="" title="{$product->name|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}" width="{$largeSize.width}" height="{$largeSize.height}"/>`code` it works wihtout any change of ProductController.php. But on other places like Cart, Viewed-Products_Block or New-Products_Block your suggestion don't work.

Comment: Hello. Cart and Product List has his own Controllers. If you want the same behavior in all shop you must override all this controllers too. I will add another option for you in my answer. Good luck.